# Snapchat API error: Something Went Wrong Invalid redirect_uri

Tags: api, authentication, snapchat

I'm getting this snapchat error after trying to setup the api. It allows the user to login and then tells them of this issue. I have tried multiple redirect uris and none have worked so far. Does anyone have suggestions for how to solve this?

```
import Snap from './snap.js'

  window.snapKitInit = function () {
        var loginButtonIconId = "my-login-button-target";
        // Mount Login Button
        snap.loginkit.mountButton(loginButtonIconId, {
          clientId: ID,
          redirectURI: "https://socialdemo-b729a.web.app",
          scopeList: ["user.display_name","user.bitmoji.avatar","user.external_id",],
          handleResponseCallback: function () {
            snap.loginkit.fetchUserInfo().then(
              function (result) {
                console.log("User info:", result.data.me);
                document.getElementById("display_name").innerHTML =
                  result.data.me.displayName;
                document.getElementById("bitmoji").src =
                  result.data.me.bitmoji.avatar;
                document.getElementById("external_id").src =
                  result.data.me.externalId;
              },
              function (err) {
                console.log(err); // Error
              }
            );
          },
        });
      };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js,
          sjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://sdk.snapkit.com/js/v1/login.js";
        sjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, sjs);
      })(document, "script", "loginkit-sdk");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something Went Wrong Invalid redirect_uri

Setup Redirct URI on Snapchat Developer Console

- Initial Version
- Redirect URIs for OAuth

your uri should be same in

in your metadata (application level)

```
<meta-data android:name="com.snapchat.kit.sdk.redirectUrl" android:value="Enter Your URI"/>
```

in Activity Level

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="hoopsnap"  // here
                    android:host="snap-kit"    // here
                    android:path="/oauth2"/>   // here
            </intent-filter>
```

Working properly for me